# add new columns to a dataframe giving each column different names in a loop

Tags: r

here i have a dataframe and vector

```
names  mpg   spd   wt  ast   alp
c1     0.34  12    34   43   2
c2     0.56  34    98   23   10
c1     0.9   847   43   23   20
c3      NA   234    34  34    45
c4      34    87    32   23   87 
c5      89    98    98   NA    NA
```

The above is my dataframe, i'm finding the correlation of attributes like (mpg,spd),(mpg,wt),(mpg,ast),(mpg,alp),(spd,wt) and so on nC2 iterations and need to append those values in a new column with a specific name in a new dataframe

```
vec=c('c1','c2','c4','c5')
 for(i in 1:length(vec))
    { 

    tb=cbind(p1,p2)  #p1,p2 are data frames attributes for correlation eg:contains characters
    tb[,ncol(tb)+1]=b #b is a dataframe which have stored correlation values of attributes
    names(tb)[,ncol(tb)+1]=vec[i]  
    }
```

Here I want to append new columns with the names in vector and to append the values in b 
my desired ouptut :

```
p1   p2   c1   c2    c3     c4    c5
mpg spd   43   0.4   23    87    23
mpg wt    76    23   19    43     12
```

Comment: Assign the column names out of the loop: `colnames(tb)[,2:(length(vec)+1)]=vec`

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop? The code is very strange

Comment: @Asha question is not at all clear. Can you give example and desired output?

Comment: I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have some dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(numeric(1000))
```

You can add more columns with names to it in a loop by using its `list` syntax. `data.frame`s are special lists after all.

```
> is.list(x)
[1] TRUE
```

You can add more columns in a for-loop like this:

```
vec=c('c1','c2','c4','c5','c6')
for(i in 1:length(vec)){
    newCol <- numeric(1000)
    x[[vec[i]]] <- newCol
}
```

Resulting in:

```
> head(x)
  numeric.1000. c1 c2 c4 c5 c6
1             0  0  0  0  0  0
2             0  0  0  0  0  0
3             0  0  0  0  0  0
4             0  0  0  0  0  0
5             0  0  0  0  0  0
6             0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Do note though that this isn't really good practice, and doesn't scale well. You don't really want to be growing objects like this, because of the cost of having to reallocate memory. If you know beforehand howmany columns you are going to need (and you do, since you are looping over their names), it is better to just create the entire dataframe, and fill it in a loop afterwards.